# Is there any reporting tools or methods available for Code Churn and coverage for Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, reporting

Please can anyone assist.

I need to find a way to report on the number of code changes per developer at any time (the number of line changes). I.e File X had 10 line additions for developer Y.

I know that with on-prem servers this can be done, but have not found a way (api, tool etc) for Azure Devops Cloud to report on Code Churn and Coverage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/perspective-code-analyze-report-code-churn-coverage?view=azure-devops-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/table-reference-code-churn?view=azure-devops-2019

Is anyone aware of anything out there that may assist me in reporting on this?

Thank you for your time and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Churn and Coverage feature is not supported in Azure DevOps services currently.

There are extensions [Count Lines of Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dealogic.cloc-vsts-extension) you might find helpful to count code lines in build pipeline and the result will be reported as a section on the build summary page. And extension [Recent Code Commits Widget](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kshyju.RecentCodeCommitsExt) to show the recent code commits in Dashboards.

There are also extensions for code coverage that you can use, eg. [Code Coverage Protector](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davesmits.codecoverageprotector) or [Code Coverage Widgets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shanebdavis.code-coverage-dashboard-widgets).

You can also create scripts to call [Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the specific version of a items in your repo and count the changes. Please check the examples to call rest api in [Get started with azure devops services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

You can [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click suggest a feature and select Azure Devops) for enabling Code Churn and Coverage feature to Microsoft development team. Hope they will consider this and implement it in the future.

Comment: Thank you for this Levi.

Yip .. have seen all the above. Thought there was something I missed somewhere as I've seen 3rd party sites able to call up Code Volume for a repository 

https://gitential.com/accounts/2/projects/29?from=2017-06-01&to=2017-08-24&demo=1&share=true

Have used the rest api to at least get the number of changes but unfortunately it does not give the cloc values.

Have also requested the feature.